# NHibernate: How to insert C# [Guid] into MySQL [BINARY(16) DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid(),1))] column?

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, uuid, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

**Environment:** MySQL Server 8.0, .NET Core 3.1, MySql.Data 8.0.28, NHibernate 5.3.11

I have following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Master` (
  `Row_Id` char(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid()),
  `Path` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Row_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Following is entity definition and mapping:

```
public class MasterEntity
{
    public virtual Guid RowId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Path { get; set; }
}

internal sealed class MasterMap : ClassMapping<MasterEntity>
{
    public MasterMap()
    {
        Table("Master");

        Id
        (
            x => x.RowId,
            map =>
            {
                map.Column("Row_Id");
                map.Generator(Generators.GuidComb);
            }
        );

        Property(x => x.Path, map => { map.Column("Path"); map.NotNullable(true); map.Type(TypeFactory.GetAnsiStringType(1000)); });
    }
}
```

Following is how I `INSERT` this entity using NHibernate:

```
using(ISession session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    MasterEntity entity = new MasterEntity();
    entity.Path = "c:\whatever";
    session.Save(entity);
    session.Flush();
}
```

This inserts the record correctly. Up to here, everything is fine.

Now, I change the definition of `Row_Id` column as below:

```
`Row_Id` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid(),1)),
```

I do not change anything in my C# code. Now, the `session.Flush();` call throws below exception:

```
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not execute batch command.[SQL: SQL not available]
 ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Data too long for column 'Row_Id' at row 1
```

The error looks obvious. The `Guid` in C# is 32 and column length is 16.
What changes I need to make in my mapping or entity definition (or other part of code) to insert C# `Guid` into `BINARY(16) DEFAULT (uuid_to_bin(uuid(),1))` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, MySql.Data will store a `Guid` as `CHAR(36)`. You can use `BINARY(16)` instead by specifying `Old Guids = True;` in your connection string.

From [Connector/NET 8.0 Connection Options Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-8-0-connection-options.html):

> The back-end representation of a GUID type was changed from `BINARY(16)` to `CHAR(36)`. This was done to allow developers to use the server function `UUID()` to populate a GUID table - `UUID()` generates a 36-character string. Developers of older applications can add `'Old Guids=true'` to the connection string to use a GUID of data type `BINARY(16)`.

Answer (score 0):

The way suggested in [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71650763/5779732) works; but it has a problem.

The code in the question uses `uuid_to_bin(uuid(),1)`; the second `swap` parameter is set to `1`. With this, the INSERT works great; but when you SELECT the row, you get entirely different UUID. This is because, database drivers do not know whether the UUID is swapped or not.

Better solution is to use [`MySqlConnector`](https://mysqlconnector.net/) instead of Oracle's Connector/NET (MySql.Data.dll).

**For ADO.NET:**

Configure it as explained [here](https://mysqlconnector.net/overview/dbproviderfactories/).

> For .NET Core 2.1 or later, call `DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("MySqlConnector", MySqlConnectorFactory.Instance)` during application startup. This will register MySqlConnector’s `DbProviderFactory` implementation in the central `DbProviderFactories` registry.

<sub>My observation is that, call to `DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory` is not needed. It just works by adding reference of MySqlConnector.dll and removing reference of MySql.Data.dll.</sub>

With `MySqlConnector`, the `OldGuids=True;` setting is available but obsolete; avoid it.
Use `GuidFormat=TimeSwapBinary16;` for `uuid_to_bin(uuid(),1)` (swap parameter set to 1).
Other possible values are mentioned [here](https://mysqlconnector.net/connection-options/):

> Determines which column type (if any) should be read as a `System.Guid`. The options include:
> **`Char36`:**
> All `CHAR(36)` columns are read/written as a `Guid` using lowercase hex with hyphens, which matches `UUID()`.
> **`Char32`:**
> All `CHAR(32)` columns are read/written as a `Guid` using lowercase hex without hyphens.
> **`Binary16`:**
> `All BINARY(16)` columns are read/written as a `Guid` using big-endian byte order, which matches `UUID_TO_BIN(x)`.
> **`TimeSwapBinary16`:**
> All `BINARY(16)` columns are read/written as a `Guid` using big-endian byte order with time parts swapped, which matches `UUID_TO_BIN(x,1)`.
> **`LittleEndianBinary16`:**
> All `BINARY(16)` columns are read/written as a `Guid` using little-endian byte order, i.e. the byte order used by `Guid.ToByteArray()` and the `Guid(byte[])` constructor.
> **`None`:**
> No column types are automatically read as a `Guid`.
> **`Default`:**
> Same as `Char36` if `OldGuids=False;` same as `LittleEndianBinary16` if `OldGuids=True`.

**For NHibernate:**

- Install [`NHibernate.MySqlConnector`](https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate.MySqlConnector) from [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NHibernate.Driver.MySqlConnector/).
- Add `configuration.DataBaseIntegration(c => c.MySqlConnectorDriver());` in Session Factory configuration.
- Set `GuidFormat` in connection string as explained above.

**For other ORMs:**

Please refer to [this](https://mysqlconnector.net/overview/use-with-orms/) for usage with other ORMs.